# Get a session variable in xpath?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xpath

I have a servlet that queries a database and returns the results as XML. I set the variable in the servlet using

```
session.setAttribute("xml", xmlString);
```

How can I retrieve that attribute using XPath if that's even possible. I need to get it, parse it, and write the values to the webpage. I'm pretty new to XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example using XPath.

You can learn more at:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathSample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String simpleXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><person><name>Bob</name></person>";
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(simpleXML));
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    try {
            String name = xpath.evaluate("//name", inputSource);
            System.out.println(name);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```